# Tar paper behind vapor barrier

Tags: drywall, studs, renovation

I'm currently going down to the studs on a few walls in my (Ontario, Canada) 1980's (brick facade exterior) bungalow. I've noticed that there seems to be: drywall -> vapor barrier -> tar paper -> insulation (battinng). I can't seem to find a similar substitute for the tar paper when I'm re-applying everything. Any suggestions, or is it alight to leave it out?

Comment: Replace tar paper with building paper

Comment: The tar paper was usually placed on the outside, between the sheeting and sliding as a house wrap.

Comment: Is the tar paper in large sheets covering the wall or small pieces attached to the insulation/battening?  If on the insulation batts, then it is a second vapour barrier.  You only want one.

Comment: The tar paper was attached to the insulation batts. That does make sense as the previous vapour barrier seems to be less than 1mm thick plastic and I'll be replacing it with 8mm vapour barrier

Answer (score 1):

Tar paper **in that position** is odd, non-standard, and does not need to be replaced with anything.

Comment: Agree 100% with the _minor_ caveat that there might _possibly_ be some local building code requiring something like this. I can't fathom why or for what purpose that bit of code might want another layer here for, but it's always worth checking local regulations first.

Comment: Thank you - it was also under the insulation batting in the attic, although I was a little more familiar with attic work to feel confident in not replacing it.